# ENTITY FRAMEWORK Error in LINQ Query "An anonymous type cannot have multiple properties with the same name"

Tags: entity-framework

I have a table 'Interval' that contain multiple foreign key from "DutationType" Table
I have a written a LINQ query like this

```
var listIntervalDurationType = 
   (from I in oSanEntities.Intervals 
       select new { I.IntervalId, I.IntervalName, I.IntevalTime, 
                    I.DurationType1.TypeName, I.DurationType.TypeName, 
                    I.RetainTime });
```

But this give the error

> An anonymous type cannot have
>   multiple properties with the same
>   name"  because of anonymous types are
>   not allow multiple property with same
>   name

For resolve this error I added new property in `DutationType` entity but there is a mapping error occuring.

What is the solution for that?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var listIntervalDurationType = (from I in oSanEntities.Intervals select new {   
I.IntervalId, 
I.IntervalName, 
I.IntevalTime, 
Duration1TypeName = I.DurationType1.TypeName,  
DurationTypeName = I.DurationType.TypeName, 
I.RetainTime });
```

As message said, you can't have two properties with name `TypeName`. You should also name `Duration1` correctly in database diagram.